# Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Shell does not logout properly

Tags: 11.10, gnome, logout

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and recently installed Gnome Shell over the Unity interface. Gnome was taken from the ubuntu software center. Now, once logged into Gnome Shell, i am unable to logout from it when required. As in, when i select logout from the desktop, it shows a dark grey screen after 2 seconds and then this screen persists till eternity. No matter what key or action i do during this time, the screen persists, and i m forced to hard boot again.

i did not face any issue during logging out from the Unity. this is only with the gnome3 DE. since i am new to Ubuntu, i m finding it hard to resolve on my own.

please let me know where to check, and what to correct, to resolve this logout issue.
thanks!

Comment: nobody... anybody..everybody...? help me logout please :D

Comment: In the extremely far right corner, there is a little system tray indicator that appears grayed out, do you have one? Can you click on it? Can you post a screen shot of the upper right hand corner of your screen?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same [problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/138023/61336) and reported a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1001061). Since 2012-05-21 this problem is no longer present in my Dell Inspiron n4050 with Ubuntu 11.10 64bit and gnome-shell 3.2.2.1. One of the recent updates must have fixed the issue, so I guess it must have been fixed for you,too.