# Gnome shell does not log out properly in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, gnome, logout, display-manager, duplicate

My problem is that when I log out from a gnome shell session I get a blank screen instead of the display manager. If I close the lid to suspend and then open it again, I get the display manager and I can log back in.

This does not happen with Unity. When I log out from a Unity session I get the display manager without any problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64bit, with gnome-shell version 3.2.2.1. I already checked `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`, and it's set to `/usr/sbin/lightdm`, as it should be, according to this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/84485/61336.

This is the exact same problem described here [Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Shell does not logout properly](https://askubuntu.com/q/85788/61336), but as you can see, I provide some additional information. I tried to leave a comment in the original question to avoid a duplicate, but I don't have enough reputation. I also tried to ask in the meta section what to do in order to avoid a duplicate in this situation, but again, not enough reputation.

Comment: Please post the installed Gnome shell version.

Comment: My gnome-shell version is 3.2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since today I no longer have any problem logging out of a gnome-shell session. I guess one of the recent updates must have fixed the issue, but I don't know which one. I reported the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1001061), but I'm not sure the report had anything to do with the fix. Anyways, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gnome 3.4 then be ready for it because 3.4 is not fully supported by 11.10
You will have broken packages,etc.

I have experienced it on my 11.10 and now also experiencing the Awesome performance with no problem in 12.04

Also you can try reconfiguring lightdm by entering the following command in the terminal:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

Hope it solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried reconfiguring lightdm as you suggested and it didn't solve the problem. Besides, I get this message: `dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME missing
dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE missing` This message seems to be related to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/+bug/706354).

Comment: First check if this file of yours is empty-

"/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf". 

If yes then follow this link.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files

Comment: @ cantillon - it seems to be a bug , please report the bug by following http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug.

Comment: @Nirmik I checked `/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf` and it is not empty. It looks ok to me.

Comment: @tijybba I'll report the bug. Thanks for your comment.